# Meaning of annotations in native code from JIT compiler

Tags: java, jit, jvm-hotspot

I'm wondering about some annotation-like extra information in the assembly code obtained via the -XX:+PrintOptoAssembly command line option (JIT compiler output) with the fast_debug build of OpenJDK version 6-src-b23-05_jul_2011 on i686 GNU/Linux.

Within the assembly code there are some "annotations" after the label of each block:

```
02c   B2:  #    B14 B3 <- B1 B13  Freq: 1
...
063   B11: #    B15 B12 <- B4 B3  Freq: 9.53674e-07
```

My first guess is that `B14 B3 <- B1 B13` is some control flow information and `Freq: 1` some information about the frequency this label is reached. Are these annotations branching hints (on platforms which support them)? Are they (publicly) documented?

Additionally, what is the meaning of `P=...`, `C=...` and `,s`?

```
02a     Je,s  B13  P=0.000000 C=6700.000000
```

Please let me know if you need a code example.

Comment: A came accross an explanation on the HotSpot developer list: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/hotspot-dev/2009-November/002422.html (this post but also others in this thread).

B5: # B6 B7 <- B8 B9 gives the list of predecessor blocks (B8 and B9) and successor blocks (B6 and B7) for block B5.

P=... is calculated from taken / not-taken probabilities.

C=... is a total counter (for taken or not-taken?).

,s marks short branches.

I still don't know whether branch hints are emitted.